# Plot each year of a time series on the same x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have a time series with daily data that I want to plot to see how it evolves over a year. I want to compare how it evolves over the year compared to previous years. I have written the following code in Python:

```
xindex = data['biljett'].index.month*30 + data['biljett'].index.day
plt.plot(xindex, data['biljett'])
plt.show()
```

The graph looks as follows:
A graph how the data evolves over a year compared to previous years. The line is continuous and and does not end with the end of the year which makes it fuzzy. What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From technical perspectives, it happens because your data points are not sorted w.r.t. date, thus it goes back and forth to connect data points in the data frame order. you sort the data based on `xindex` and you're good to go. to do that: (first you need to put `xindex` in `data` dataframe as a new column)

```
data.sort_values(by='xindex').reset_index(drop=True)
```

From the visualization perspective, I think you might have several values per each day count, thus `plot` is not a good option to begin with. So IMHO you'd want to try `plt.scatter()` to visualize your data in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten as follows:

```
 xindex = data['biljett'].index.month*30 + data['biljett'].index.day
 data['biljett'].sort_values('xindex').reset_index(drop=True)
 plt.plot(xindex, data['biljett'])
 plt.show()
```

but gets the following error message: 
ValueError: No axis named xindex for object type

Comment: Hi. These kind of additional and subsequent info should go in the comment section, not as an answer, I have not been notified of your comment until now! so please transfer it in a comment on my answer... and as for your question, you should sort by an existing column in your dataframe, while you have assigned `xindex` as an independent variable. change it as `data['xindex'] = ...` and you're good to go. still recommend scatter plot. I think it fits better